# enum field error while baking model all

Tags: cakephp

I  run the command cake bake model all  and got the below error.
Schema generation error: invalid column type enum('Used','New') does not exist in DBO in /var/www/showcase_admin/cake/libs/model/cake_schema.php on line 601

Answer (score 2):

I believe Cake doesn't support `enum` , as it is a vendor specific datatype

There are several user submitted solutions around this problem; one such is [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jzimmerman/2006/10/03/baked-enums). I haven't used it but I'm sure you will be able to find something relevant with a bit of digging.